# Detect acoustic echo or sidetone in sound file or device

Tags: audio, phone-call, aec, acoustics

I need to detect acoustic echo/sidetone from a unmuted telephone handset.

Basically I am calling a telephone handset on my mic muted computer. I then play a sound from the computer to the phone and record the incoming audio from the handset.

I need to detect if the telephone I called was on mute or not.
If its not muted I should see some sidetone/echo in the audio file.

Currently I am having issues seeing any echo in the raw audio.

Is there any software or algorithms I can run the audio file through to detect the echo/sidetone?

Is there any specific tones or freq I should play to generate the biggest echo?

Answer (score 1):

Echo and sidetone are generally looked at separately although they do overlap - sidetone is sound that 'leaks' from the microphone in the handset to the speaker in the same handset (the leak can be in handset, the phone or sometimes the local linecard in the exchange/PABX), and echo is sound that travels from one party in a call to other party at the far end of the call and then 'leaks' back along the connection to the original party again.

For echo if the distance is short then it effectively behaves the same as sidetone as the user simply hears a portion of what they have said played back at almost exactly the same time they are saying it. If the distance is long enough that the 'echoed' sound is heard after the user has spoken then it sounds more like an 'echo'.

You should be able to visually see the effect by generating a sound clip into the microphone of the handset being tested which has a very distinct shape when you graph it, and then comparing that with a graph of the sound received in the earpiece of the handset. To test echo you generally need to simulate a delay somehow, or else the echo will look just like sidetone.